# Facebook share permission application review android

Tags: android, facebook

I tried submitting my APK for a review so I can get the share permission on Facebook.

1. Uploaded screenshots so they can go step by step to the share option on my application.
2. Set the correct languages/locales that my application is using.
3. Wrote in the description field step by step how can they go to the share option on my application.
4. Configured the Facebook application correctly with my key hash, package name and class name.

They refused my submit with the following message

on Android - Your provided file has been configured incorrectly. For iOS Simulator Builds, follow our instructions and resubmit. For Android submissions, please build a .APK file for upload.

Notes from our review team for your last reviewed submission
Android

**I tried downloading the file you have provided for your app, however I received this message on a new webpage: "Invalid Request" Please resubmit with a new .APK file so that our team can finish testing your app.**

Any ideas why are they refusing my application? Or is there a way to contact Facebook what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: They're not refusing anything, they couldn't get your APK. Either your build is corrupted or the link is wrong. If you uploaded the APK to your own servers you might need to set the mime type to "application/vnd.android.package-archive" to allow direct install from url

Comment: Hey, so finally how did you resolve this. I am getting the same problem

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** "Invalid request" is a way to say "something got wrong in the upload process". Perhaps a funny charachter in filename, or even spaces. Or a file too big. Without a precise error message you can only guess what went wrong.

Perhaps the problem is in process of signin the application. Check if your developer key has expired. This is the publish process in brief:

- Remove debug info / debug mode
- Check/increment in manifest.xml android:versionCode and android:versionName
- Check that ALL resouces are in the res folder
- Check that ALL graphic is resized to minumum (no 16Mb jpg for an icon...)
- Compile and sign APK

(For Eclipse)

- Select project in Package Explorer
- File -> Export
- Android -> Android Application
- Follow the wizard
- Test the APK on a real device

Comment: Nope.. The apk file is working fine for me. How it would be configured incorrectly for them?

Comment: If the apk works fune, I can guess that the problem arises during uploading process: top suspects are filesize and filename

Comment: Else if you provided a direct link, there's something wrong in this link / file permissions on server. How do you are submitting your APK?